# Powershell ConvertTo-CSV custom headers

Tags: powershell, csv

Does Powershell support using custom header names when converting data to CSV? I'm convertering user data from Active Directory and want to use other names in the headers than the property names.

My code:

```
$adusers | select  givenName,sn,telephoneNumber,SamAccountName,physicalDeliveryOfficeName,Title,mobile | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ';' | Out-File -FilePath $thefilepath
```

Comment: Show the code that you are working with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to skin this cat. 
You can create new custom objects from the output and name the properties what you'd like:

```
$adOutput | Foreach-Object{
   New-Object PSObject -Property @{
      UserName = $_.SamAccountName
      ...
   }
} | Export-Csv ...
```

You can also do that using calculated properties:

```
$adOutput | Select Name,@{Name='UserName';Expression={$_.SamAccountName}} | Export-Csv ...
```

Comment: Here's a great post on the topic, [Name that Property](http://powershell.org/wp/2013/04/29/name-that-property/).