# I need to display my result in three columns using power shell script

Tags: powershell

I have my current script display results but when it comes up it just puts everything in one long column but they are in order.  Any ideas how I can get three columns called "computer name" "Patch#" "Installed?".

Below is my code

```
$strCategory = "computer"
$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$ObjSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.filter = ("(objectCategory=$strCategory)")
$colProplist = "name"
foreach($i in $colProplist){
    $objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($i)
}
#Finds all operating systems and computer names
$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()

foreach($objResult in $colResults){    
    $objComputer = $objResult.Properties;
    $names = $objComputer.name

    # Define Hotfix to check
    $CheckKBS = @("KB2937610", "KB4019264")

    # Query the computers for the HotFix
    foreach($name in $names){
        foreach ($CheckKB in $CheckKBS) {
            $HotFixQuery = Get-HotFix -ComputerName $name | Where-Object {$_.HotFixId -eq $CheckKB} | Select-Object -First 1;
            if($HotFixQuery -eq $null) {
                Out-file C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\12.csv -Append -InputObject "computername: $name"
                Out-file C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\12.csv -Append -InputObject "“KB Patch: $CheckKB"
                Out-file C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\12.csv -Append -InputObject "Hotfix $CheckKB is not installed on $name"
            } else  {
                Out-file C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\12.csv -Append -InputObject "computername: $name"
                Out-file C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\12.csv -Append -InputObject "KB Patch; $CheckKB"
                Out-file C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\12.csv -Append -InputObject "Hotfix $CheckKB was installed on $name by $($HotFixQuery.InstalledBy)"
            } 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: The solution would probably be creating a custom object to store your data and then exporting it to a csv. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690857/powershell-convertto-csv-custom-headers for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're outputting raw text into a CSV which is OK but you have to maintain the intended destination format.

out-file is going to output raw text, one per line. That is why your calls are creating a single column. You can change your code to collapse your output to 1 line that is separated by commas:

```
Out-file C:\Users\xx\Desktop\12.csv -Append -InputObject  “computer name: $name,KB Patch: $CheckKB,Hotfix $CheckKB is not installed on $name”
```

This will write 1 raw line to your CSV file. Your fields will be respected as columns assuming the rest of the CSV file is intact.

I doubt you want to repeat your headers per line but wanted to show you what it would look like. Now you are going to want to write the initial line of the CSV file before you start your loop to output the headers:

```
Out-file C:\Users\xx\Desktop\12.csv -Append -InputObject  “Computer Name,KB Patch,Hotfix”
```

Then just remove the header stuff from the lines written inside your loop. This does mean that the header will be written with each run so you are either going to want to wipe the file at the start or you are going to want to test if it exists before you write the header.

There are better ways to do this but this doesn't require you to make significant changes to your work. I would create a custom object for each record, create a collection of those objects, and then export them via export-csv. If that would better suite your need please just comment a request for it.